# echo a specific custom taxonomy term on a different custom taxonomy archive

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I'm not having much luck trying to find anything to help with this...

I have a custom taxonomy('XYZ') archive all the posts in this archive also have an other common custom taxonomy('ABC').

I'm looking for a way to echo the other custom taxonomy similar to `<?php single_term_title(); ?>` something like `<?php single_term_title_ABC(); ?>`

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the terms applied to a post from a certain taxonomy, use [`wp_get_post_terms`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms). Inside the loop add:

```
$abcterms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'ABC');
foreach($abcterms as $abc) echo $abc->name;
```

Comment: Can I push my luck and ask if you know of a way to echo nothing/blank if the custom taxonomy has more than 1 term on the archive page?

Comment: are the terms passed in the query? and display blank for what? your question is not clear, it would be better if you created a new qs with details.